# Circulation of a vector field through a cylinder inside a sphere.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, stokes-theorem

Let's say i have the solid $E$ bounded by the cylinder $x^2+y^2=2x$ and the upper part of the sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=4$. Also i have the vector field $F=(y-z, yz, -xz)$.

I was asked to find the circulation of $rot \ F$ through the vertical and spherical face of $E$.
$\hspace{3.7cm}$[image]

I know i have to use Stokes theorem (or perhaps i can work with Gauss theorem). The real problem is how do i work with this solid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\nabla\cdot\nabla \times F = 0$

So using Gauss' rule.  The net flow is 0.

sphere + cylinder wall + disk = 0

$\int \nabla \times F = \oint F \cdot dr$

Through the bottom disk.

$r = (\cos \theta+1, \sin \theta, 0)$

$\int_0^{2\pi} -\sin^2\theta d\theta = \pi$

But that is oriented clockwise.

If we flip the orientation (pointing outward, instead of upward) $-\pi$

Through the top of the sphere:

$r = (\cos \theta+1, \sin \theta, \sqrt {2-2cos\theta})\\
\sqrt {2-2cos\theta} = 2\sin \frac 12 \theta$

$\int_0^{2\pi} -\sin^2\theta + (2-2\cos\theta)(-\sin\theta) + (\sin\theta)(2-\cos\theta)(\cos\theta)+ (1+\cos\theta)(\sin\frac12\theta)(2\sin\theta) d\theta$

Comment: Thanks! But $\int^{2\pi}_0-\sin^2\theta \ d\theta=-\pi$ i gues it is already outward oriented. Also could you explain me how do you parametrize the top of the sphere like that?

Comment: $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 4 \implies (\cos\theta + 1)^2 + \sin^2\theta + z^2 = 4\implies z^2 = 2-2\cos^2\theta$ oops, $z = 2\sin \frac 12 \theta$ guess I  forgot to take a square root in there!